# Visual Studio DevExpress some tools are disabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

I installed devexpress today and some tools in the toolbox were not visible, I right clicked and chose show all, they all came, but now they are disabled. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUkEt.png)

I also used the Reset Toolbox feature but it didn't fix it. I have tried delete .tbd files but it didn't work.